Left join but use group by field that on right table
I have two tables, first one has detailed order information.

Table A: Restaurants id, brand id, date, order id, order value (usd)
Table B: Restaurants id, restaurants name, brand name

I want to create a table that shows monthly revenue grouped by restaurant names.
Example:
       December  November  October
Res 1
Res 2
Res 3

My SQL query:
SELECT 
  A.restaurant_id,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN A.date >= '2024_12_01'
      THEN A.order_value
    ELSE 0
  END) AS December_Revenue,
FROM A 

LEFT JOIN B ON A.restaurant_id = B.restaurants_id
  
GROUP BY B.restaurant_name
ORDER BY December_revenue DESC

My SQL query facing this error:

column "A.restaurant_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
in an aggregate function

How can I solve it? I want to show restaurant names on result table because ids not useful

The error message says it all. SELECT the name instead of id.

A complete [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Also note that tables have columns, not fields.

But the names on the table B

Doesn't matter. But why do you LEFT JOIN? (Do you have orders from non-existing restaurants?)

You need to include every "non-calculated" column in the GROUP BY clause (from SELECT). It's not enough to group by name if you're querying id in the end.  As @jarlh mentioned, this is the solution to the question in its current state. If you don't agree, then you must have phrased the question incorrectly. This is the only conclusion that can be drawn from it.

I have a solution with a sub-select for you. But I can't post it because the topic is closed.

Here is my solution (unformatted): SELECT X.restaurant_id, X.December_Revenue, B.restaurant_name FROM ( SELECT A.restaurant_id, SUM(CASE WHEN A.date >= '2024_12_01' THEN A.order_value ELSE 0 END) AS December_Revenue FROM A GROUP BY A.restaurant_id ) X LEFT JOIN B ON A.restaurant_id = B.restaurants_id ORDER BY December_revenue DESC

You don't even have restaurant_name in your SELECT.  How do you expect to show the value???

When you are using aggregation function you have to in GROUP BY clause list every column which you have in your SELECT, so you have to list A.restaurant_id in GROUP BY becouse you use this column in SELECT.
In my opinion you haven't to using B.restaurant_name, A.restaurant_id is enough.

Thanks for the comment, but I want to show results by names not ids. How to show names on result table?

Just replace A.restaurant_id in SELECT to B.restaurant_name
SELECT 
  B.restaurant_name,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN A.date >= '2024_12_01'
      THEN A.order_value
    ELSE 0
  END) AS December_Revenue,
FROM A 

LEFT JOIN B ON A.restaurant_id = B.restaurants_id
  
GROUP BY B.restaurant_name
ORDER BY December_revenue DESC

